# class inheritance multiple choice

Tags: python, class, inheritance, tkinter

Using tkinter and i have two exactly the same classes (tk and toplevel) so i merged them but need to choose which window type i want to inherit.

**code**

```
class Window(tk.Tk, tk.Toplevel):
    """ Basic root window (derived from tk.Tk) """
    def __init__(self, window, title = "None", geometry = ("300x150"),
                 resize = True, minMax = True, prompt = True):

        if window == "root":
            tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        elif window == "toplevel":
            tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        else:
            raise WindowTypeError("Incorrect window type '%s'" % window)
```

Is there a better way or a more pythonic way of doing this?

**SOLVED**

```
import functools
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

# / import own modules
from exception_classes import WindowTypeError
# \ import own modules

class Window(object):
    def __init__(self,
                 window,
                 title    = "None",
                 geometry = ("300x150"),
                 resize   = True,
                 minMax   = True,
                 prompt   = True):


        if window == "root":
            self.window = tk.Tk()
        elif window == "toplevel":
            self.window = tk.Toplevel()
        else:
            raise WindowTypeError("Incorrect window type '%s'" % window)

        self.window.title(title)
        self.window.geometry(geometry)
        self.window.resizable(resize, resize)
        self.window.config(bg = "#ffffff")
        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", functools.partial(self.quit_window, prompt))
        self.window.attributes("-toolwindow", not minMax)
        self.raise_window()

    def quit_window(self, prompt = False):
        """ Confirmation for kill method """
        if prompt:
            if not messagebox.askyesno("Quit Application", "..."):
                return -1

        self.kill()

    def raise_window(self):
        self.window.attributes("-topmost", 1)
        self.window.attributes("-topmost", 0)

    def kill(self):
        """ Destroys the window """
        self.window.quit()
        self.window.destroy()


W = Window("root")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tk` and `Toplevel` are not exactly the same classes, and you shouldn't inherit from both.

If you are creating the main window, your class should inherit from `Tk`. If you are creating any other window, inherit from `Toplevel`.

If you want the same code to be used by both the root window and other windows, make your class a subclass of `Frame`, and then create a factory that will create either a root or toplevel window that contains the frame.

```
class MyApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
def create_window(window_type):
    if window_type == "root":
        root = tk.Tk()
        app = MyApp(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    else:
        top = tk.Toplevel()
        app = MyApp(top).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_window("root")
```

Another strategy would be to make your app inherit from neither, and use composition:

```
class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self, window, ...):
        if window == "root":
            self.root = tk.Tk()
        else:
            self.root = tk.Toplevel()
        ...
```

Comment: The way i use them they will be exactly the same. i had two classes the same but one inherited from each window. seems a bit of a waste.

Comment: Thank you, i am going to use the composition method